# Flutter snippet didn't work in statefull widget android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, code-snippets

i dont know, after flutter 3.0.0 update, i can't use snippet in android studio. maybe i can, but inside a function. i cant easily import material.dart. but i used snippet in it worked (i can use snippet without flutter snipet plugin in android studio before).

this flutter snippet didn't work inside statefull widget,

[image]

but it works inside function.
[image]

i can use snippet before finally using flutter snippet plugin, but when i upgrade flutter to 3.0.0, i cant use it. and when i use flutter snippet plugin, i can't do like @override.
i've try updating all the plugin, reinstalling android studio, but it doesn't work.

any solution ?
i've already comfortable making flutter app with android studio, and i actually doesn't wanted to use vscode to make flutter app..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me too, after I've updated flutter and android studio on my Ubuntu 22 I can't use `initState` and `setState` snippet even I've installed snippet plugin. Then I can use it again by changing Live Template setting, but not like before (works on `StatefulWidget` only). You can follow this steps:

1. Open *File->Settings->Editor->Live Templates->Flutter* then click `initS`
   [image]
2. Click ***Change*** button on the bottom and check mark ***Flutter*** then click ***Apply***
   [image]
3. Finish, you can use `initState` snippet now.

You can add `setState` or other template you want by clicking `+` button on ***top-right*** and fill all needed.

`Happy coding!` :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write in Widget build function. Currently you are in the wrong scope

Answer (score 0):

Same here. So how i solved this issue! I just use `Ctrl+O` for overriding any method.
N:B sometimes hints don't work. so I have to press `ESC` a couple of times or navigate to another page and come back again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first type in the `@override` annotation first, and then type `stlss`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).